# Calling a shell rsync command from C

Tags: shell, rsync, c

I am creating a basic C file in order to learn the basic Linux commands a little better. I am trying to implement a tar back up function. I am struggling to implement it in C (still learning C) so that it will work with my shell.

My question, How can I create a back up of my directory in C

This is all I have so far (Just the Linux Command)

**Code**

```
#define ROOT /home/network
#define DESTIN /home/network/backups
int shell_backUp(char **args)
{
    printf("Backing Up....");
    rsync -avu $ROOT $DESTIN;
    printf("Back Up complete");
}
```

Comment: Your "question" is quite vague, but more importantly, you didn't actually ask a question.  Try to reform the above as a question, and take a look here:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Not to sound condescending, but the first problem is that C and shell script are different languages and cannot be intermixed and fed unmodified to the same compiler.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question with a proper question, I was under the impression that from my .c file I could call Linux commands? and such could call the rsync command to back up the directory

Comment: in C, you could use the `system()` function or you could use `execvp()` to run the rsync command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define ROOT "/home/network"
#define DESTINY ROOT"/backups"

int main()
{
    printf("Backing Up....\n");
    system("rsync -avu " ROOT " " DESTINY);
    printf("Back Up complete\n");
}
```

The first function that is called in your program is a function named `main`, that is why I've replaced the name, but you can change this and call your function from `main`.

In your `define` clauses the quotes were missing.
The `system` function will take a string as argument and call your shell passing your string to it.

In C/C++, strings with only spaces/tab/breaklines between them are concatenated. For Instance, you could write:

```
const char* str = "The " "quick "
"brown "
"fox.";
```

And you would end up with `str = "The quick brown fox."`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have seen the system() call be fore and was thinkning of using it. When I implemented your code I got an error saying 'rsync: not found', is there a library I should be using as well for this?

Comment: Can you execute rsync in your shell? You might need to install it first.

Comment: Also make sure that rsync is in your `PATH`. Execute `sh -c 'echo $PATH'` and then `whereis rsync`, and make sure rsync is there.
On debian-based distros you can install it with `sudo apt-get install rsync`.

Comment: Has it solved your problem?